# Turning an =IFS statement into a script in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In a current Google Sheets book (on the main tab, named "Master") this formula currently sits in Column E, starting in Row 3, going down to the end of the sheet.

```
=IFS(V3="","",AND(V3<>"", AJ3=""),"Needs Invoice"
,AND(AJ3<>"", AM3=""),"Payment Due",AI3<>AN3,"Partial Payment Due",AI3=AN3,"Paid")
```

For clarity:

- If "V" is blank, "E" is also blank
- If "V" is NOT blank and AJ is blank, "E" is "Needs Invoice"
- If AJ is NOT blank and AM is blank, "E" is "Payment Due"
- If AI and AN both have values and are NOT equal, "E" is "Partial Payment Due"
- If AI and AN both have values and are equal, "E" is "Paid"

This works for what I need it to do, but I'd much rather have this as a script to fill column E and run on edit of columns V, AI, AJ, AM or AN (the columns used in the above formula).

I have no idea how to go about getting this started, as it is way above my skill level. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If "V" is blank, "E" is also blank
- If "V" is NOT blank and AJ is blank, "E" is "Needs Invoice"
- If AJ is NOT blank and AM is blank, "E" is "Payment Due"
- If AI and AN both have values and are NOT equal, "E" is "Partial
  Payment Due"
- If AI and AN both have values and are equal, "E" is "Paid"

```
function ifToScript() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Master');
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    if(!vA[i][21]) {
      vA[i][4]='';
    }
    if(vA[i][21] && !vA[i][35]) {
      vA[i][4]="Needs Invoice";
    }
    if(vA[i][35] && !vA[i][38]) {
      vA[i][4]="Payment Due";
    }
    if(vA[i][34] && vA[i][39] && vA[i][34]!=vA[i][39]) {
      vA[i][4]="Partial Payment Due";
    }
    if(vA[i][34] && vA[i][39] && vA[i][34]==vA[i][39]) {
      vA[i][4]="Paid";
    }  
  }
  rg.setValues(vA);
}
```

Try the below as an `onEdit()`. Note: vA.length will always be 1.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss=e.source;
  var rg=e.range;
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  var col=e.range.columnStart;
  var row=e.range.rowStart;
  var colA=[22,35,36,39,40]
  if(sh.getName()!='Master'){return;}
  if(colA.indexOf(col)>-1 && sh.getName()=='Master'){
    var rg=sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,40);
    var vA=rg.getValues();
    for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
      if(!vA[i][21]) {
        vA[i][4]='';
      }
      if(vA[i][21] && !vA[i][35]) {
        vA[i][4]="Needs Invoice";
      }
      if(vA[i][35] && !vA[i][38]) {
        vA[i][4]="Payment Due";
      }
      if(vA[i][34] && vA[i][39] && vA[i][34]!=vA[i][39]) {
        vA[i][4]="Partial Payment Due";
      }
      if(vA[i][34] && vA[i][39] && vA[i][34]==vA[i][39]) {
        vA[i][4]="Paid";
      }  
    }
  rg.setValues(vA);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you a ton for the answer! However, when I try and run it, nothing appears to happen

Comment: Try it again.  I left something out.

Comment: Good summary of what you wanted.

Comment: Actually, one more question for you. I know I can change the function to be "function onEdit()" and it runs once column E is edited, but is it possible to instead make it so that it will run when V, AI, AJ, AM or AN are edited?

Comment: You wouldn't want to run this function onEdit () because it looks at every row in the spreadsheet and that might take some time.  So it would be better to do that one line at a time.  I'll take a look at it.

Comment: Sorry to ask you yet another question, but I just noticed an issue that I'm running into with this that maybe you can help with. Everything you posted works great, but it is having the unfortunate effect of removing formulas and leaving the values behind. Luckily everything in this sheet is scripted except for this one formula in A3:A  : =G3&", "&R3&", "&V3 (in ColA, repeats to the end of the sheet). Any suggestions on how to either incorporate that or maybe ignore and leave the formula?

Comment: You can change `var rg=sh.getDataRange()` to `var rg=sh.getRange(1,2,sh.getLastRow(),sh.getLastColumn()-1);` and then you'll have to decrement all the column indices by one.  You can do a similar thing with your header rows as well.  Remember, column indices begin at zero not one like columns.